# How can I put user input into a list using eval?

Tags: python-3.x

thanks for helping.
I am having trouble with the following code:

```
digitsList = input("Enter any list of 0 or more digits in the form [digit, digit, ...]:")

if element == int(list[index]):
   index += 1
   return True

else:
   index += 1
   return False
```

for example the user entered : `[1,2,3]`

then I get a following error :

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '['
```

I tried everything I can but not being able to solve it.

Comment: Sorry I am a starter, the problem is I want the user to enter in the form [digit, digit, ...], but I do not want the "[" or "]" in the acutal list because I want to see if 0 == int(digitList[0]) and it wont work if digitList[0] is "[". Is there a way to avoid "[" or "]" being added into the list

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to read your code the way you posted it, but user input could be put into a list using the .append feature.

For example:

```
list = digitsList.append("what the user inputs goes here")
```

Comment: Sorry I am a starter, the problem is I want the user to enter in the form [digit, digit, ...], but I do not want the "[" or "]" in the acutal list because I want to see if 0 == int(digitList[0]) and it wont work if digitList[0] is "[". Is there a way to avoid "[" or "]" being added into the list

Answer (score 0):

You are giving a wrong input. The input entered by the user should be like this in a single line : `1 2 3`. If you are supposed to take a list as input, do this :

```
digitslist = map(int, raw_input("Enter any list of 0 or more digits in the form [digit, digit, ...]:").split())
```

Input : `1 2 3`

Output : `[1, 2, 3]`

The `input()` function is supposed to take only one `int`, `float` or `string entered with quotes` as input.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am having the following code restrictions since I am doing homeworks for my class. The only Python functions I am allowed to use are:input() eval() and len()

Comment: and I have to ask the user to enter in the form [digit, digit, ...]

Comment: @litterbeach : If you are working in `python 3.x`, do this : `eval(input())` and if in `python 2.7`, do this : `eval(raw_input())`, where the user inputs : `[1,2,3]`.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:

```
x = [i for i in eval(input("Enter comma seperated"))]
```